# How public is a public Azure DevOps project?

Tags: azure-devops

is a "Public" DevOps project accessible by

1. everyone on Azure DevOps
2. only by the organization members
3. all members of the Azure Active Directory that is linked to the organization.

What I want to achieve is 3. over 2. but not 1.

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A public project means "*Anyone on the internet can view the project. Certain features like TFVC are not supported.*" which is the 1 in your list, this you can see when you create a new project in Azure DevOps service :

[image]

You can find more detailed informaion at the doc [What is a public project?](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/organizations/public/about-public-projects?view=azure-devops), it says "*Users that aren't signed into the service have read-only access to public projects on Azure DevOps.*".

> What I want to achieve is 3. over 2. but not 1.
>
> 2. only by the organization members
> 3. all members of the Azure Active Directory that is linked to the organization.

What you are seeking for is a private project in fact, create a new private project and add the organization users to this project, or if your organization is connected to AAD then you can directly add anyone who's in the AAD to this project with no need to add them to your organization first.

This you can find more information at the doc [Add members to your project](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/organizations/accounts/add-team-members?view=azure-devops#add-members-to-your-project).

Comment: Thank you for the answer. In this case the tool explains the issue better than the documentation ;)

Comment: "then you can directly add anyone who's in the AAD to this project with no need to add them to your organization first."
Is there an easy way to add all users of the AAD as a member of a team? I have found an account that has the same name like the AAD that is linked to the organisation.

Answer (score 0):

It seems for public project to access, admin/project owner need to invite the required user.

Ref: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/organizations/public/invite-users-public?view=azure-devops

Public projects are not that public...